# why is my ctp not getting any data for one of the tables i am subscribing to?

Tags: kdb

I have few ctps subscribing to a tp.
subscription is established with no problems but data doesn't seem to hit 1 of my ctps.

I have 2 ctps subscribing to the same table. one is getting data the other doesn't.

I checked. u.w and I can see the handles being open for the said table but when I check the upd on my ctp... it receives all other tables except this one.

upd on my ctp it's a simple insert. I cannot see any data at all for the table. the `t` parameter is never set to the the name of the table I am interested in. I don't know what else to check. any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. the pub logic is the default pub logic.

no errors in the tp.

UPDATE1: I can send other messages and I receive data from the tp for other tables. issue doesn't seem to persist I dr just prod. I cannot debug much in prod

Comment: what's your .u.pub set to?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing more of your code it's hard to create a good answer.
Couple things you could try:

- Check if you can send a generic message (e.g. `h(+;1;2)`) from your tp to ctp via the handle in `.u.w` this will make sure the connection is ok.
- If you can send a message then you can check if the issue is in your ctp. You can see exactly what is being sent by adding some logging to your `upd` function, or if you thing the message isn't getting that far, to your `.z.ps` message handler function, e.g. `.z.ps:{0N!x;value x}` will perform some very basic client side logging.
- If you can't send a message down the handle in the tp then it's possible there's other network issues at play (although I expect you would be seeing errors in your tp if that was the case). You could check `.z.W` in your ctp in this case to see if the corresponding handle for the tp is present there.
- Can also send a test update to your tickerplant and add logging along each step of the way if you really want to see the chain of events but this could be quite invasive.

Comment: hey. thanks. I did all this. I did all the basic checks. I can send messages to the ctp but it seems like the handle is being skipped on publishing

Comment: If you are using vanilla kdb+ tick and you can guarantee that all other tables are publishing and that there are no other potential publishers then I don't think it's possible for a client handle to be skipped. The only way I could see this happen is if you are subscribed for specific symbols that are not getting updates (ie you subscribed with something other than backtick). In that case `.u.sel` will filter everything out.

Comment: Also it's worth checking `.z.W` in the tickerplant. This will hold the mapping of outgoing message sizes to handles. If you're seeing a steadily increasing number next to the ctp handle then it may indicate a slow subscriber.